# VirtualBox headless: Why can't I get the guestproperty network address?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, headless

I have installed Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 (Trusty) on a VirtualBox client (bridged network connection, Guest Additions installed). I sometimes run the client in headless mode (rather than through the VirtualBox GUI) and access it via SSH. To start such a client and get its network address, I normally:

```
nohup VBoxHeadless --startvm <VM_NAME> & #start as background process
#wait a bit for it to start up
VBoxManage guestproperty get <VM_NAME> "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP"
```

This works for most clients (Debian, Windows, I don't remember if it worked for my Ubuntu 13.10 client). If this fails, I can request all details, but even here the network address doesn't come up.

```
VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate <VM_NAME>
```

My guestproperties for the 14.04 client are as follows:

```
Name: /VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Product, value: Linux, timestamp: 1402485749624026000, flags: 
Name: /VirtualBox/HostInfo/GUI/LanguageID, value: en_US, timestamp: 1402652779530499000, flags: 
Name: /VirtualBox/HostInfo/VBoxVerExt, value: 4.3.12, timestamp: 1402652779119725000, flags: TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST
Name: /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Vbgl/Video/SavedMode, value: 1366x722x32, timestamp: 1402485750186131000, flags: 
Name: /VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Version, value: #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:02:19 UTC 2014, timestamp: 1402485749625558000, flags: 
Name: /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VersionExt, value: 4.3.12, timestamp: 1402485749627827000, flags: 
Name: /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Revision, value: 93733, timestamp: 1402485749628338000, flags: 
Name: /VirtualBox/HostGuest/SysprepExec, value: , timestamp: 1402652779118360000, flags: TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST
Name: /VirtualBox/HostGuest/SysprepArgs, value: , timestamp: 1402652779118595000, flags: TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST
Name: /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/Version, value: 4.3.12, timestamp: 1402485749627214000, flags: 
Name: /VirtualBox/HostInfo/VBoxRev, value: 93733, timestamp: 1402652779119840000, flags: TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST
Name: /VirtualBox/HostInfo/VBoxVer, value: 4.3.12, timestamp: 1402652779119633000, flags: TRANSIENT, RDONLYGUEST
Name: /VirtualBox/GuestInfo/OS/Release, value: 3.13.0-29-generic, timestamp: 1402485749624971000, flags: 
Name: /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/HostVerLastChecked, value: 4.3.12, timestamp: 1402485781945719000, flags:
```

My workaround is to start the client with the VBox GUI, log in and type `ifconfig` to get the address, shut it down, and start it again headless, but I'd prefer to avoid that. How can I get the network address from a headless Trusty VirtualBox client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the machine starting and waiting at the GNU GRUB screen (visible in the Preview). Starting it via the GUI once (to get the login screen), stopping it, and starting it headless seems to work.

I'm guessing it waits at GRUB after a kernel or Guest Additions update. (But I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the mac address for the newtworking interface that you want to get the address for. You can do this using `ifconfig` or I think its listed in the machine config for the virtual interface.
2. From the host (or which ever machine you are using to ssh) install [arp-scan](http://linux.die.net/man/1/arp-scan).
   `sudo apt-get install arp-scan`. arp-scan lists all mac and ip address pairs on the network.
3. Then the command to run arp-scan and grep out the mac address you want would look somehting like

`sudo arp-scan 10.253.0.0/24 | grep -i <mac address>`

You may have to specify an interface if you have more than 1 e.g. `--interface=eth0`. And your network and subnet may be different.

Now for extra credit you could use `awk` to pull out just the ip address and put together your ssh command, and have everything done in one little script.

This is what I would do.

pseudocode:

```
start vm
sleep 1 min
ip=$(apr-scan | grep | awk print $2)
echo $ip
ssh <user>@$ip
```

Comment: I've discovered that the cause is not actually persistent in my case (see my answer), but thanks for this, it could help in the future!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with arp approach is - you have to initialize TCP/IP or UDP communication with the box prior to find it on the system arp table.

So you have to know the IP ;) - chicken and egg problem.

However this way should work:

```
VBoxManage list runningvms 

"some_box_default_1486476025646_64328" {d20b1b0e-a5xf-4afc-94e0-4ea78d70539f}

VboxManage guestproperty get {d20b1b0e-a5xf-4afc-94e0-4ea78d70539f} /VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/1/V4/IP

Value: 10.XX.XX.XX

   Net/0  for eth0   Net1 for eth1
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching and no good result, I found this article: https://itsfoss.com/how-to-find-what-devices-are-connected-to-network-in-ubuntu/

in resume:

1. use ifconfig to know your_ip
2. use nmap nmap -sn your_ip/24

it show all device connected to the LAN, if there are few is easy to know your VM IP.